# Split up the non bootable partition and install Ubuntu in any.

Tags: 12.04, partitioning

I'm trying to partition part of my hard drive that's non bootable and install another version of ubuntu on the part of the disk with free space. Can anyone point me in the direction of information on how to do so?

Comment: plz upload gparted screenshot to imgur.com and post the link here.And tell me how much space did you want to allocated for the another version?

Answer (score 0):

- Make an Ubuntu live USB and boot from it.
  [image]
- During installation , 
  Choose the 3rd option :  **Something else**
- Then in the partitioning window you can delete the partition you prefer and create 2 partitions from the free space.
- Then install Ubuntu in any of the 2 new partition you prefer by formatting it to Ext4 and defining the mount point as '/'.
- Else, if you don't want to format the non bootable partition, launch the GParted app either from your previous version of Ubuntu or by Live booting the new Ubuntu.  [image]
- Then right click the non bootable partition and choose **Resize/Move** . Now you can easily adjust the size of the partition and free up space from it. After creating the free space, make a new volume out of it. Later follow the Ubuntu installation steps.